# Convert SQL Server stored procedure to Oracle procedure to query from tables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to move from SQL Server to an Oracle database. I have to move my stored procedure from SQL Server to Oracle that do a query from multiple table with an `INNER JOIN`. I am trying to clarify few things here.

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
[dbo].[QueryAll] 
    @score1_min int = 0,
    @score1_max int = 999,  
    @type1 varchar (1) = '%',
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM FUNIJ1 uni
    INNER JOIN CAPI99 api99 on api99.application_id = uni.application_id
    INNER JOIN CAPI41 api41 on api41.application_id = uni.application_id
    INNER JOIN CAPI10 api10 on api10.application_id = uni.application_id
    WHERE 
        api10.score1 BETWEEN @score1_min AND @score1_max 
        AND uni.type1 LIKE @type1
END
```

And my Oracle procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE QUERYALL 
(
  SCORE1_MIN IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
, SCORE1_MAX IN NUMBER DEFAULT 999 
, TYPE IN VARCHAR2 
) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM FUNIJ1 uni
    INNER JOIN CAPI99 on CAPI99.APPLICATION_ID = uni.APPLICATION_ID
    INNER JOIN CAPI41 on CAPI41.APPLICATION_ID = uni.APPLICATION_ID
    INNER JOIN CAPI10 on CAPI10.APPLICATION_ID = uni.APPLICATION_ID
    WHERE 
        CAPI10.score1 BETWEEN score1_min AND score1_max 
        AND uni.type LIKE type
END REPOQUERYALL ;
```

1. I used % as default query parameter to return all values in SQL Server
   in case of no input from user. I am not sure what I have to use in Oracle as default value to return all.
2. List item Oracle is using new term INTO following to `SELECT *`. I am not sure whether I need to use INTO or cursor in this case. I don't know WHICH will be appropriate here and HOW to use it.
3. I'd appreciate if anybody can transfer this SQL Server to an Oracle procedure. I am not sure that my Oracle is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me with Sys_Cursor. Thanks @TS for the help that guide me to this answer.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE QUERYALL 
(
o_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS 
BEGIN
O_Cursor := NULL;

OPEN O_Cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM FUNIJ1
    INNER JOIN CAPI99 on CAPI99.APPLICATION_ID = FUNIJ1 .APPLICATION_ID
    INNER JOIN CAPI41 on CAPI41.APPLICATION_ID = FUNIJ1 .APPLICATION_ID
    INNER JOIN CAPI10 on CAPI10.APPLICATION_ID = FUNIJ1 .APPLICATION_ID
    WHERE 
    ----
    ----
END QUERYALL;
```

When you use this procedure in Java to display the table, you need to call Sys_Cursor into Resultset.

```
String sp= "{CALL QUERYALL(?)}"; // Procedure calling with Sys_Cursor
cst = con.prepareCall(sql);
cst.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cst.executeUpdate();
rs = (ResultSet) cst.getObject(1);              
while(rs.next()) {
----
----
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to understand about Oracle stored procedure - unlike in SQL Server, you can't just do `SELECT ...` in any programming block, unless this is subselect or `select... into...`.

If the goal is to return record set from procedure, in Oracle, you have to add a `Sys_RefCursor` output parameter and open this ref cursor with your `select` statement.

You're not far away - [check this example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets) .And remember, when you do `Open <cursor_name> FOR ...`, what comes after `FOR` can be dynamic SQL string or just compiled SQL.

Comment: Thank you T.S. So when I am adding 'RefCursor' those Oracle examples mention about IN parameter too. Is this mandatory?

Comment: Yes. If you want to return data from Oracle stored procedure, you need to declare `output` parameter of `Sys_refcursor` type to return this data. Another (similar) way of doing it, is by declaring function `create or replace Function ... return sys_refcursor`. But it is really same thing. `Return` is just a type of output parameter. So, if you use stored procedure, you can return multiple ref cursors. In sql server you can simply write `select* from t1; select * from t2` - you have 2 resultsets. In oracle, for each `select` to return data you need `sys_refcursor` parameter:`Open p1..;Open p2`

Comment: `IN` parameters are only if you need them to pass something to SP. Ref cursor must be `OUT`

Comment: @TS, I modified my code like this, but still I'm making some error
    'create or replace PROCEDURE QUERYALL 
(
--------
, o_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS 
BEGIN
OPEN o_Cursor FOR SELECT FROM QCFUNIJ1 uni;
INNER--------
-------------
END REPOQUERYALL ;'

Comment: I just tested it - it works in oracle `create or replace procedure aa (pa in varchar2)
as
  rc sys_refcursor;
  rec dual%rowtype;
begin
    open rc for select * from dual where dummy like pa;
    fetch rc into rec;
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(rec.dummy); 
end;
/` 
Test -->
`begin 

   EIDMADM.aa('%X');
end;
/`

So, basically, it is working fine in `LIKE` with parameter, just like SQL Server. You facing syntactical issue now, not systematic

Comment: I see `rec dual%rowtype` for one table. If I'm joining multiple tables, how do I modify this code to display data from multiple tables? Like if I'm fetching data from `Table1+Table2+Table3` using inner join..

Comment: @KodS Declare your `type` with the columns you need and declare `rec` of that type. there is plenty of Oracle documentation on this available online